# What, if anything, does 'neoplanastic' mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across this word in the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions-structured/#SetUpPro):

> one might hold that certain words simply have no semantic values, and so make no contribution to propositions. So-called **neoplanastic** ‘ne’ in French might be thought to be an example of this.

Searches have found only one other [use](http://artandlanguage.co.uk/AL_ebooks/Excuse%20me,%20but%20I%20never%20said%20exactly%20so.pdf), but there it is essentially just repeating the the same sentence.

Searching for 'ne'+'french' led me first [here](https://www.translations.co.uk/why-does-french-use-both-ne-and-pas-for-negation/#:%7E:text=In%20archaic%20French%20or%20Old,have%20a%20un%2Dnegated%20form.), where I learned that 'ne' is disappearing from spoken French, even though, etymologically, it is the 'ne' in 'ne...pas' etc. that expresses negation. This seemed promising, but then [this article](https://french.yabla.com/lesson-%22Ne%22-without-a-%22pas%22-241) about 'ne' without 'pas' says

> The *ne* in this sentence is called a *ne explétif* (also known as *ne **pléonastique***). Instead of negating the clause (as it does when combined with *pas, plus, personne*, etc.), this *ne* emphasizes the general feeling that the clause expresses.

Pléonastique is translated as 'pleonastic', which is [defined](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pleonastic) as

> Adjective
> relating to or having the characteristics of pleonasm; needlessly wordy or redundant:
> pleonastic expressions such as “I heard it with my own ears.”

'Redundant' would seem to make sense in the context of the source phrase, so is neoplanastic likely just a typo for pleonastic?

Comment: *Ne pléonastique* is typically translated as *pleonastic ne*.  That's pretty darn close to "neoplanastic ne." My guess is typo.  Or a person who couldn't exactly remember the phrase *pleonastic ne*.

Comment: Surely the *neo-* means *recently* pleonastic? The *ne* in the usage *ne ... pas* has become pleonastic, so it is neopleonastic. Perhaps the author liked the way that sounds.

Comment: @WeatherVane, *neopleonastic* makes sense, but *neoplanastic*?  Recently *planastic*?  Also, it's a little silly for the author to make up his or her own term (*neopleonastic ne*) and then refer to the neologism as "so-called"

Comment: I was editing the comment to get the spelling right. I was a bit thrown by the closing question "is neoplanastic likely just a typo for pleonastic?" It seems more likely to be a typo for 'neopleonastic' but one way or the other, there is a typo.

Comment: @WeatherVane I wondered about that, but let it go because I doubted that the pleonastic ne was a recent development - though I have no specific reason for thinking that... Neo- would seem to be more suitable as a prefix indicating recency in the case of ne being dropped in spoken  French, but that seems to be separate issue than the pleonastic ne: in this case, the ne-less sentence still expresses negation, while the pleonastic ne explicitly does not, at least according to the article I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so is *neoplanastic* likely just a typo for *pleonastic*?

Almost certainly. I can't find any other uses of the word, and the established word "pleonastic" works perfectly here.